# Import data from txt file to table

Tags: sql, sql-server, bulkinsert, sql-server-2017

I need to import data from a txt file separated with ; but the are blanks lines in between, and it throws an error whenever it wants to convert the blank lines.

```
Create table #temp (Dato1 varchar(50) collate Modern_Spanish_CI_AS,
                          Dato2 varchar(50) collate Modern_Spanish_CI_AS,
                          Dato3 varchar(50) collate Modern_Spanish_CI_AS,
                          Dato4 varchar(50) collate Modern_Spanish_CI_AS,
                          Dato5 varchar(50) collate Modern_Spanish_CI_AS,
                          Dato6 varchar(50) collate Modern_Spanish_CI_AS,
                          Dato7 varchar(50) collate Modern_Spanish_CI_AS,
                          Dato8 varchar(50) collate Modern_Spanish_CI_AS,
                          Dato9 varchar(50) collate Modern_Spanish_CI_AS
                         
                            )


Declare @Sql varchar(500)
set @Sql = 'BULK INSERT #temp FROM ''' + 'C:\Users\Nico\Desktop\text.txt' + ''' WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR='';'', ROWTERMINATOR=''\n'')'
print @sql
exec (@sql)

select * from #temp

drop table #temp
```

This is the error

> Bulk load data conversion error (truncation) for row 22, column 1 (Dato1).

and this is the txt file

```
00008134;01;004477;000000000000000;49439974       ;-----------------        ;3100;N;26092022;
00008134;01;004477;000000000000000;49439974       ;-----------------        ;3100;N;26092022;
                                                                                                                                                                 
00008134;02;029003;000000000000000;56901908       ;-----------------        ;3100;N;15092022;
00008134;02;029003;000000000000000;56901908       ;-----------------        ;3100;N;15092022;
00008134;02;029003;000000000000000;56901908       ;-----------------        ;3100;N;15092022;
```

Is there a way to import the file and ignore the blanks lines?

I try to only create a table with one dato nvarchar(max) then delete the rows with ' ' data in it. And I finish with a table with data separated with ; (00008134;01;004477;000000000000000;49439974       ;-----------------        ;3100;N;26092022;). Can I transform the data from the row in several columns in another table?

Comment: Which row of the five rows you posted is row 22?

Comment: Have you tried _not_ including blank lines in the source file(s)?

Comment: The blank line is the line 22. I paste a portion of the file, the entire file is about 1300 lines. Deleting the lines manually is not and option (the import is made through system that calls the query), i need that the user who do the import avoid touching the file